# How to get the page height and width in Excel Interop Assembly 14 and 15?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop, com-interop

I'd like to get the height and width of the pages of an Excel worksheet so I may create a bitmap that has the same size as the page.

I am using the following interop assemblies:

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 14**

and

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 15**

In [this example](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Header-and-Footer/How-to-Add-Watermark-to-Excel-Sheet-in-C-VB.NET.html) that uses version 11 of the interop assemblies, there is a `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` propery each on the `PageSetup` property of the `Worksheet` class/interface.

However, in the version of assemblies I am using, there is no such property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pagesetup_members.aspx

How do I get the page height and width for all the pages of a worksheet? Or are they different now and I have to iterate over each page in the `Worksheet.PageSetup.Pages` collection?

If I wanted to simply set the header of a worksheet to an image whose size equals the page height and width, what do I do?

Comment: Are you using the PIA? Try referencing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Tools.Excel instead?

Comment: Oh yes, I totally forgot about those (what's that called) hosted thingies that add to the interop assemblies. Giving that a try.

Comment: For VSTO isnt it under the Globals... `Globals.Sheet1.PageSetup.`

Comment: Not doing VSTO. Using it from a desktop (console) app for now but eventually, want to do it inside a Web server. I tried and the host thingies from the `Tools` assembly also do not have the objects I am looking for viz. `Worksheet.PageSetup.PageWidth` and `Worksheet.PageSetup.PageHeight`. Also, the `Worksheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture` is now a read-only property. Apparently, Microsoft removed the option to set a picture in the header or footer in Excel with the newer versions of Office? I can set a header in an Excel worksheet in Office 2016 but not in Office Online.

Comment: *eventually, want to do it inside a Web server* - FYI server side office automation is not supported or recommended, if possible you should find an alternative method.

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you much.

Comment: The kb article is 257757, I was going to tell you but wanted to see this issue first. ClosedXML is the best alternative IMHO.